# Defining packet loss as a percent of packets sent/received in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I'm looking at two audio channels: `SendAudio and ReceiveAudio` coming from a WebRTC call. For each respectively, we can see the following metrics:

```
AudioSend
----------
packetsLost
packetsSent

AudioReceive
----------
packetsLost
packetsReceived
```

My question is, what is the correct equation to calculate the packet loss for each? Are the 'lost' packets included in the packetsSent/packetsReceived?

For example, packet loss as a percent for two WebRTC events could be defined as:

```
AudioSend Packet Loss as a Percent

                             currentEvent.packetsLost - previousEvent.packetsLost
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(currentEvent.packetsSent + currentEvent.packetsLost) - (previousEvent.packetsSent - previousEvent.packetsLost)
```

Note: we need two events as packetsLost and packetsSent are both running sums (so we need the delta between two events).

This would be the case if the lost packets are NOT included in the `packetsSent` value (i.e. they would have to be added for to sum the total amount of packets that were SUPPOSE to be sent).

From Igor's input:

AudioSend Packet Loss as a Percent

```
packetsLost
-----------  *  100
packetsSent
```

AudioReceived Packet Loss as a Percent

```
           packetsLost
-----------------------------   *   100
packetsReceived + packetsLost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PacketsLost` is not included in the `packetsReceived`, but included in `packetsSent`. `PacketsSent = packetsReceived + packetsLost + packetsDuplicated`. `PacketsDuplicated` will be discarded by the receiver. So I suppose you want to calculate audio quality based on the packets loss, I think you should use bit rate as audio quality.

```
          const lastTotalBytesReceived = lastScanResult.totalBytes;
          const currentTotalBytesReceived = currentScanResult.bytesReceived;
          lastScanResult.totalBytes = currentTotalBytesReceived;
          const receivedBitsDelta = 8 * (currentTotalBytesReceived - lastTotalBytesReceived);
          const passedSeconds = (currentTime - lastScanResult.time) / 1000.0;
          lastScanResult.quality = Math.round(Math.min(100, receivedBitsDelta / expectedAudioBitRate * 100));
          lastScanResult.time = currentTime;
```

`ExpectedAudioBitRate` for OPUS will be 35000 and for other codecs 70000

Comment: Hey Igor - thank you for the answer. At the moment, we're just looking at packet loss. If that's the case, then I updated my answer with what I believe is correct.